# Can I skip array elements with `list` assignment?

Tags: php, arrays

Let's say I have a function returning the following array:

```
function fruits(){
  $arr = array('apple','orange','banana','pear');
  return $arr;
}
```

And I'd like to assign the third and forth array elements to a variables without using of temporary variable:

```
list(NULL,NULL,$banana,$pear) = fruits();
```

This code will not work, but it will show the idea of the way I'd like to use `list` construction.

The reasons I'd like to use `list` is the following:

1. I use PHP 5.3 so construction like `fruits()[2]` will not work.
2. I can do more assigns within one line of fairly readable code
3. I'd like to skip temporary variables to reduce code size and increase its readability.

So is there any possibility to use `list` and skip some array elements?

Comment: *within one line of fairly readable code* i think thats not true ... list is a pseudo-function and by the way your function is fruits() doesn't make sence

Answer (score 7, accepted):

php 5.5.14

```
function fruits(){
  $arr = array('apple','orange','banana','pear');
  return $arr;
}

list(,,$banana,$pear) = fruits();

echo $banana; // banana
```

Comment: Works with PHP 5.3.9 aswell.

Answer (score 3):

PHP 7.1+

```
[,,$banana,$pear] = fruits();
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can skip elements: just omit the variable name:

```
list(,,$banana,$pear) = fruits();
```